# Linq-Sql Oracale object relational data type, is it possible?

Tags: c#, oracle, .net-4.0, dblinq

I have recently been trying to set up a .Net application which will connect to an oracle database using object relational data types, I would like to do this using the Linq-Sql framework, however when using tools such as DbLinq it does not seem to allow for the object relational data type.

So I was wondering if anyone knows a way to do this?

Thanks,
Alex.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Oracle has been working on, and is now beta-testing, [their Entity Framework provider](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/downloads/oracleefbeta-302521.html):

> ODAC Entity Framework and LINQ Beta has arrived! Itincludes support for Entity Framework, LINQ to Entities, Model-First, Entity Data Model Wizard, and more.

They've even posted [a tutorial using Model-First development](http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/db/dotnet/EntityFrameworkOBE/EntityFrameworkOBE.htm).

According to their [statement of direction](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/topics/dotnet/whatsnew/oracle-entity-framework-sod-130214.pdf), they plan to have this production-ready sometime in 2011.

I've been meaning to test this out but I haven't had the need to in any current projects. It's a shame -- a year or so back I would have really appreciated this ;-)

Let me know how it is!